# Help aligning tables

Tags: floats, subfloats, positioning

I need to align 1 table to the right and two to the left,
the layout I want to achieve is something like this:

[image: Table layout]

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \subfloat[]{% 
  \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
  \hline
  0 & 1\\
  \hline
  2 & 1\\
  3 & 1\\
  4 & 2\\
  5 & 3\\
  4 & 8\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  }  \qquad
  \subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{ccc} 
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3\\ 
    3 & 7 & 4\\
    4 & 5 & 4\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{ccc} 
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3\\ 
    3 & 7 & 4\\
    4 & 5 & 4\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }~
\end{figure}
```

Ted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution for both variants, two and three subfloats
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\minipage[b]{0.49\linewidth}
 \centering
 \subfloat[]{%
 \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}\hline
        0 & 1\\\hline
        2 & 1\\
        3 & 1\\
        4 & 2\\
        5 & 3\\
        4 & 8\\\hline
 \end{tabular}}%
 \quad
 \subfloat[]{%
 \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc} \hline
       1 & 2 & 3\\ 
       3 & 7 & 4\\
       4 & 5 & 4\\\hline
    \end{tabular}\\[5ex]
    \begin{tabular}[b]{ccc} \hline
       1 & 2 & 3\\ 
       3 & 7 & 4\\
       4 & 5 & 4
    \end{tabular}\\\hline
  \end{tabular}}%
\caption{the one for all}

\endminipage\hfill
\minipage[b]{0.49\linewidth}
 \centering
 \subfloat[]{%
 \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}\hline
        0 & 1\\\hline
        2 & 1\\
        3 & 1\\
        4 & 2\\
        5 & 3\\
        4 & 8\\\hline
 \end{tabular}}%
 \quad
 \begin{tabular}[b]{c}%
 \subfloat[]{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc} \hline
       1 & 2 & 3\\ 
       3 & 7 & 4\\
       4 & 5 & 4\\\hline
    \end{tabular}}\\[5ex]
 \subfloat[]{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{ccc} \hline
       1 & 2 & 3\\ 
       3 & 7 & 4\\
       4 & 5 & 4\\\hline
    \end{tabular}}%
  \end{tabular}%

\caption{the one for all}
\endminipage
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fine on its own, but when the `\subfloat` captions are added the right one is further down than the left caption. Added the parent tabular on the left fixes that.

Comment: @Martin: no, then you did something wrong ...

Comment: To clarify: the tables are still aligned correctly, but not the sublabels created by `\subfloat`. The reason seems to be the extra space caused by the bottom `\hline` s. After removing them in the both left and bottom right tabular the sublabels are also correctly aligned.

Comment: Martin: Where are the sublabels (a) and (c) not aligned?

Comment: In the OP, the two right tabulars share one sublabel, the `\subfloat` is outside both tabulars. I was assuming that is what the OP wants. The resulting (a) and (b) are not aligned in this case.

Comment: @Martin: that will also no problem for me. As I said, _no_ need for the double tabulars. I'll edit my example

Comment: @Herbert: you are of course right, there shall be a (better) solution without double tabulars, but it can be fixed with some.

Comment: Ah, putting the last `\\\hline` into the outer tabular. Very nice idea, I wouldn't had thought of it. BTW, I just ordered your table book last week over Dante. It's still on its way to Ireland.

Answer (score 3):

Use tabulars inside tabulars:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \subfloat[]{% 
    \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
        \hline
        0 & 1\\
        \hline
        2 & 1\\
        3 & 1\\
        4 & 2\\
        5 & 3\\
        4 & 8\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \end{tabular}%
  }
  \quad
  \subfloat[]{% 
    \begin{tabular}[b]{c}%
        \begin{tabular}{ccc} 
            \hline
            1 & 2 & 3\\ 
            3 & 7 & 4\\
            4 & 5 & 4\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \\\\%
        \begin{tabular}[b]{ccc} 
            \hline
            1 & 2 & 3\\ 
            3 & 7 & 4\\
            4 & 5 & 4\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}%
        \\
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note, that the both parent and bottom tabular have a `[b]` argument. The left tabular must also be placed inside a parent tabular to get the same spacing to the subfloat label.

/edit: removed `{ }` for inner `tabular`s.

*Results:*

Without left parent tabular:

[image: no parent tabular]

With left parent tabular:

[image: parent tabular]

The added margins can be removed by replacing `{c}` with `{@{}c@{}}` in the parent tabulars.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer The solution is good, but I would recommend you change the `\figure` to table so any captions can refer to tables.

Comment: @Yiannis: Done, the OP used `figure`, so I first did not changed set.

Comment: @Martin: The left outer tabular is not needed and also not the `{..}` for the sub tabulars

Comment: @Herbert: You are definitive right about the `{..}`, I confused that with `tabularx`, where they are needed.

Comment: @Martin: no, tabularx also didn't braces around the body

Comment: @Herbert: They are required for `tabularx` inside another `tabularx`. Its manual says in section 3: "`tabular` and `tabular*` environments may be nested with no restriction,
however if one `tabularx` environment occurs inside another, then the inner one must be enclosed by `{ }`."

Comment: @Martin: that is already a difficult case and will not always work