# Top-align two parboxes with tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, boxes

I am looking for a two-column solution: The left column contains one table, the right column several tables. I was thinking of using `parbox`es as follows:

```
\parbox[t]{2cm}{\vspace{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
x & x & x\\
x & x & x\\
x & x & x\\
x & x & x\\
x & x & x
\end{tabular}}
\hfill 
\parbox[t]{2cm}{\vspace{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
x & x & x\\
x & x & x
\end{tabular}\\[1em]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
x & x & x 
\end{tabular}}
```

But this creates a nasty space between whatever comes before the two columns. Without `\vspace{0pt}`, the two first tables in both columns are not top-aligned. I am looking for a top-aligned solution without the extra space before the two columns.

[image]

Comment: I can't see the image.

Comment: I'm able to see the image. Could you make a complete compilable example out of it, please.

Comment: Similar question: [Help aligning tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9993/2975).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppress the `\vspace{0pt}` commands and use the optional argument to control the position of the `tabular`s:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\noindent\parbox[t]{2cm}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
    x & x & x\\
    x & x & x\\
    x & x & x\\
    x & x & x\\
    x & x & x
  \end{tabular}
}\hfill
\parbox[t]{2cm}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
    x & x & x\\
    x & x & x
  \end{tabular}\\[1em]
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    x & x & x 
  \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use parent `tabular`s instead of `\parbox` like shown in [Help aligning tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9993/2975). Then you do not need to specify the width of the content.