# subfigure, 1 big on the left, 2 small above each other on the right

Tags: positioning, subfloats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help aligning tables.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9993/help-aligning-tables)

How to place with the package subfigure or subfig 3 subfigures as indicated in the title: 1 big on the left, 2 small above each other on the right? That is, something like this:

```
.   b
a 
.   c
```

The a subfigure roughly having the same height as b and c together.

Is a table required?

Comment: See the answers to the related question [Help aligning tables.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9993/help-aligning-tables). It's for `tabular`s in this constellation, but should be easily adjustable for sub-`figure`s.

Comment: I will mark this question than as a duplicate of the linked question, OK? This connects both together and will help to keep the place tidy.

Comment: Indeed, I find it appropriate. Thanks again.