# Minipage, columns, tabular: differences in applicability?

Tags: beamer, tables, minipage, columns

This [\parbox vs. \minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/parbox-vs-minipage-differences-in-applicability) post helped me to understand the main reasons to use either `\parbox` or `{minipage}` for placing material side-by-side (`{minipage}` is usually the winner). I have a similar question but for the `{minipage}`, `{columns}`, and `{tabular}` environments. In particular, what are the differences in applicability and when do you want to use one over the other when placing material side-by-side?

The rule-of-thumb I'm using now: `{columns}` for `beamer` documents, `{minipage}` for all other documents, and `{tabular}` when there's special focus vertical rules. (Having some rule-of-thumb is very helpful for me because I'm still a beginner with this stuff and am a little overwhelmed by the available options)

Comment: You mean for putting material side by side, do you? For any other things this three environments are completely different. You can `minipage` for this, but it indent is actually a different one. Using `tabular` to get columns etc. is actually more a misuse as a use.

Comment: That's correct, for putting material side-by-side (I edited by question to reflect that). Thx for the tip on `tabular`. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short: this three environments are in the general case completely different.

`minipage` creates a mini-page, i.e. you can place several paragraphs in a box and even have footnotes in it which are shown at the bottom. It is very often used to change the text width for some material and to avoid that it is broken over a page. It is also the way to draw a frame around paragraphs etc. It can be used to place two paragraphs or other things like images and tables side by side, but this is just one of its applications.

`columns` is a `beamer` environment and good for creating, aeh, columns! Like having bullet points on the left and a graphic on the right. For normal documents use the `multicols` environment from the `multicol` package instead.

`tabular` is an environment to create tables, usually with multiple columns and rows. It can also be used to place other material like images or other whole tables in an tabular form. You can put vertical lines in it, but this is actually not recommend because it is considered bad style (see the manual of the recommended `booktabs` package).

I can see one common application, which is to place things side by side. In this case you could use all three (only in beamer), but normally `minipage` is used when you need vertical mode to add a caption ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/place-figures-side-by-side-spill-into-outer-margin/10507#10507)) or `tabular` if you need are more complex design but don't need vertical mode ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9993/help-aligning-tables)). Anyway, in theory almost any combination of them is possible.

Comment: beamer `columns` environment is not respected in `beamerarticle`, so be careful with `columns` if you want to produce one column article and a slide presentation from same source.

Comment: @Ignasi: do you know, then, why anyone would use `{columns}` instead of `{minipage}`? Sounds like `{minipage}` is the winner again.

Comment: No, except for its `T` option and easier syntax. With `columns` you don't need to know `minipage` to vertically divide a beamer slide. But if you know `minipage`, you don't need `columns`.